# Merging JSON objects with JSON sub-objects

Tags: javascript, json, object, merge

I feel like I am missing something very obvious...  I can not get JSON objects to merge and hold their sub objects.  I have four JSON objects that I need to merge.

```
Customer: {"datecreated":"12/10/2015 9:18 am","id":"5566447","entityid":"652967804","entitystatus":"13","companyname":"ABCTools Inc parent","altname":"ABCTools Inc parent","email":"jdoe@email.com","phone":"(512) 123-4567","subsidiary":"1"}

Contact: {"contact":{"datecreated":"12/10/2015 9:18 am","id":"5566544","entityid":"JohnDoe Customer","firstname":"JohnDoe","lastname":"Contact","email":"jdoe@email.com","phone":"(512) 123-4567","company":"5566447","subsidiary":"1"}}

SubCustomer: {"datecreated":"12/10/2015 9:18 am","id":"5566448","entityid":"652967805","entitystatus":"13","companyname":"ABCTools Inc sub","altname":"ABCTools Inc sub","email":"jdoe@email.com","phone":"(512) 123-4567","subsidiary":"1"}

subContact: {"subcontact":{"datecreated":"12/10/2015 7:14 am","id":"5566142","entityid":"JohnDoe SubCustomer","firstname":"Johndoe","lastname":"Subcustomer","email":"jdoe@email.com","phone":"(512) 123-4567","company":null,"subsidiary":"1"}}
```

I can merge them with out issue.  But, they do not retain their structure.  Below is the function I was originally using to merge them:

```
function concatObjects(cust,contact){
  for(var key in contact){
    cust[key]=contact[key];
  }
  return cust;
}
```

This works great on the Customer and Contact:

```
var mergedCust=concatObjects(customer,contact);

mergedCust: {"datecreated":"12/10/2015 9:18 am","id":"5566447","entityid":"652967804","entitystatus":"13","companyname":"ABCTools Inc parent","altname":"ABCTools Inc parent","email":"jdoe@email.com","phone":"(512) 123-4567","subsidiary":"1","contact":{"datecreated":"12/10/2015 9:18 am","id":"5566544","entityid":"JohnDoe Customer","firstname":"JohnDoe","lastname":"Contact","email":"jdoe@email.com","phone":"(512) 123-4567","company":"5566447","subsidiary":"1"}}
```

But, when I try it on the Subcustomer and sub contact they are simply aprended to each other, like this:

```
mergedSubCust: {"subcustomer":{"datecreated":"12/10/2015 9:18 am","id":"5566448","entityid":"652967805","entitystatus":"13","companyname":"ABCTools Inc sub","altname":"ABCTools Inc sub","email":"jdoe@email.com","phone":"(512) 123-4567","subsidiary":"1"},"subcontact":{"datecreated":"12/10/2015 7:14 am","id":"5566142","entityid":"JohnDoe SubCustomer","firstname":"Johndoe","lastname":"Subcustomer","email":"jdoe@email.com","phone":"(512) 123-4567","company":null,"subsidiary":"1"}}
```

I can see that this is because they are sub-object.  So I tried this:

```
function concatObjects(cust,contact){
    for(var key in contact){
      if(typeof contact[key]=='object'){
        cust[key]={};
        for(var subKey in contact){
          cust[key]=contact[subKey];
        }
      }else{
        cust[key]=contact[key];
      }
    }
    return cust;
  }
```

But, it still returns the same:

```
mergedSub: {"subcustomer":{"datecreated":"12/10/2015 9:18 am","id":"5566448","entityid":"652967805","entitystatus":"13","companyname":"ABCTools Inc sub","altname":"ABCTools Inc sub","email":"jdoe@email.com","phone":"(512) 123-4567","subsidiary":"1"},"subcontact":{"datecreated":"12/10/2015 7:14 am","id":"5566142","entityid":"JohnDoe SubCustomer","firstname":"Johndoe","lastname":"Subcustomer","email":"jdoe@email.com","phone":"(512) 123-4567","company":null,"subsidiary":"1"}}
```

Below is how they should look when all merged together:

```
{
  "datecreated": "12\/10\/2015 9:18 am",
  "id": "5566447",
  "entityid": "652967804",
  "entitystatus": "13",
  "companyname": "ABCTools Inc parent",
  "altname": "ABCTools Inc parent",
  "email": "jdoe@email.com",
  "phone": "(512) 123-4567",
  "subsidiary": "1",
  "contact": {
    "datecreated": "12\/10\/2015 9:18 am",
    "id": "5566544",
    "entityid": "JohnDoe Customer",
    "firstname": "JohnDoe",
    "lastname": "Contact",
    "email": "jdoe@email.com",
    "phone": "(512) 123-4567",
    "company": "5566447",
    "subsidiary": "1"
  },
  "subcustomer": {
    "datecreated": "12\/10\/2015 9:18 am",
    "id": "5566448",
    "entityid": "652967805",
    "entitystatus": "13",
    "companyname": "ABCTools Inc sub",
    "altname": "ABCTools Inc sub",
    "email": "jdoe@email.com",
    "phone": "(512) 123-4567",
    "subsidiary": "1",
    "subcontact": {
      "datecreated": "12\/10\/2015 7:14 am",
      "id": "5566142",
      "entityid": "JohnDoe SubCustomer",
      "firstname": "Johndoe",
      "lastname": "Subcustomer",
      "email": "jdoe@email.com",
      "phone": "(512) 123-4567",
      "company": null,
      "subsidiary": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

I believe what I'm missing is how to just take that whole second object and place it inside of the first object, no matter what datatype is is.

I've Googled around a lot, but and not finding anything specific to this issue...  Thanks for any insight into this.

Comment: finally how should they look like?

Comment: @gurvinder372 I updated the question to add that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that they are part of one json right now as

```
var oneObj = {
   customer: {},
   contact: {},
   subcustomer: {},
   subcontact: {}
};
```

create another object as

```
var finalObj = {};
finalObj.customer = oneObj.customer;
finalObj.customer.contact = oneObj.contact;
finalObj.customer.subcustomer = oneObj.subcustomer;
finalObj.customer.subcustomer.subcontact = oneObj.subcontact;
```

Comment: Wow...  Thanks...  Figured I was missing the obvious.  Though, I did not think it was that obvious.  lol.  Thanks!

Comment: @W3BGUY Happy to help. Thanks you for the quick upvote and accept